# Selenium clicking on link before it's visible

Tags: python, selenium

I'm running into a problem where Selenium is clicking on a link before it's being displayed on the screen.

I've tried using both:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,('menu-link-dashboard'))))
```

and

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,(self.ws.cell(row=i, column=j).value))))
```

The issue I'm running into is that with both of the above, Selenium is finding the link before it's actually displayed on the screen. It then manages to click on the link, but because it hasn't been properly loaded yet, it gives an incorrect behaviour (it expands its sub menu and then collapses it).

Can anyone offer a solution?

Comment: Please provide an example so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: It's tricky to reproduce. There's a menu item that when clicked on, expands a sub menu. If that link is clicked on before the home page loads, the sub menu expands and then instantly minimises.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it.
The problem was caused because I was waiting for the link to be visible. I actually needed to wait for the home page to be visible (which only happened 2 seconds after the menu links were visible).

I changed the Webdriverwait to be performed on an object on the home page instead.